# C++ library for 3D curve fitting

Tags: library, c++, 3d

I have a file holding a lot of points in R3 that approximately forms a knot. I know basic programming in Python and C++, but I am not sure how I would go about writing a program that could approximate a curve for a set of points. Could anyone suggest any libraries or methods I could use to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [the Curves library](https://github.com/loco-3d/curves).

It's header only if you plan to use it in C++.

From the documentation, it gives tools to:

> create exact splines of arbitrary order (that pass exactly by an arbitrary number waypoints)

Example code from the [PDF documentation](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/loco-3d/curves/master/doc/curves.pdf) (sorry I had to screenshot as the PDF breaks copy/paste):

[image]

Comment: From the description, I don't get that this library would approximate or do a fitting. Do you have some example code on how to implement such a fitting?